# Проблемы с CSP в проекте с react router и nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-dom, csp

Я делаю React приложение где использую React router, и на бэкенде nodejs+express.
Моя задача такова, при обращении на http://example.ru - я отдаю одно react приложение, а при http://example.ru/admin - другое.
Проблема в том, что если я к примеру перехожу на http://example.ru/shop через react router(NavLink) мои настройки CSP работают. Но есть я использую строку браузера то настройки CSP не работают, вернее работают только на http://example.ru .

Мои настройки CSP
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src http://localhost:3001 https://sun9-23.userapi.com https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net https://gspics.org data:">`

Ошибка если перейти на http://example.ru/shop через строку браузера
[image: Ошибка]

В инструментах разработчика браузера, meta тег есть.
[image: В инструментах разработчика браузера, meta тег есть.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, ваш бэкенд издаёт HTTP заголовок Content-Security-Policy, политика которого конфликтует с политикой из мета тега:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
  default-src *;
  img-src http://localhost:3001
       https://sun9-23.userapi.com
       https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net
       https://gspics.org
       data:
  ">
```

Ка видно из сообщений консоли браузера: *because it vioaltes the following Content Security Policy **"img-src 'self' data:"*** - нарушенная политика совсем не та, что опубликована в метатеге.

Если вы имеете 2 CSP одновременно (meta + HTTP header или meta + meta), то будет действовать наиболее ограничительная из них.

Возможно на бэкенде у вас подключен пакет Helmet 4, а он по умолчанию издаёт свою дефолтную политику (Helmet 3 - не издаёт).

Как я понимаю, React рендерит страницу на стороне клиента, поэтому всегда действует `meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">` который был установлен при первой загрузке страницы с сервера. Изменить его средствами яваскрипта (без перезагрузки страницы с сервера) [невозможно](https://csplite.com/ru/csp/test240/).

PS: Судя по сообщению консоли, у вас блокируется скрипт реКапчи в директиве `script src 'self'`, но в метатеге директива `script-src` отсутствует и вместо неё должна работать `default-src *`. Но скрипт `www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?...`, таки, блокируется - значит на странице действует политика не из вашего метатега, а какая-то другая.

PPS: Вот тест [CSP для reCaptcha](https://csplite.com/ru/csp/test298/), добавьте нужные правила в свой `<meta>`, когда разберётесь кто у вас на бэкенде публикует CSP.

Comment: Да, я использовал helmet и он задавал свою политику. Просто добавил в исключение. `helmet({ contentSecurityPolicy: false })` . Спасибо, что подсказали.